# Why does .NET Core behave differently with Task - Win VS. Linux?

Tags: linux, windows, .net-core

I have a code written in C# and C++ running on .NET_Core which works on multiple threads and continues repeatedly.

When it gets to the following line:

> Task.Factory.StartNew( () => something.DoJob(data));

it behaves differently on linux than the way it behaves on Windows.

In windows: all working great,
In linux:   takes a lot of time until it enters the DoJob

When I just leave "something.Dojob(data)" (without the Task part) - it works great on linux, but not on windows(asynchronous problems).

My question is: Does it make sense? Is there a difference between linux and Windows when dealing with tasks or is it probably something else in my code?

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Can you provide a [mcve] demonstrating the performance difference? Also, how much time is "a lot of time"? Millisecond? Second? Minute?

Comment: I changed the whole thing to a thread, and that did the job!

Comment: StartNew executes the task on `Current` synchronization context, use `Task.Run`, don't use threads directly.